# My IP address is wrong. How can I change it

Tags: applications

I live in Iowa but my IP address is from another state. Why? I would like to change it to my area.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to your cell carrier assigning random IP addresses to the phones connected on its network. **It doesn't mean your IP address is *wrong***, it just means they don't have any available IP allocation available in your area.

The easiest thing you can do is connect to WiFi networks while browsing on the Internet, that will give websites a better idea of your location.

Installed Android apps do not care what your IP address is. If they need your location, **they will use GPS** to find your location (Google Maps does this). Websites won't use your GPS because that invades your privacy. They don't need to know your exact location, unless you *want* them to know (such as ordering off Amazon).

I hope this clears up the issue

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. Have a good day

Comment: @MelindaRohrer-Baldwin Glad to see Aaron was able to help you. If his answer solved your issue (which it IMHO did), please *accept* it (by ticking the little check-mark next to it). That way other users can recognize your question has a solution, even when seeing it in a list of questions. Thanks in advance!